# React Native - Map array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-native-share

I'm trying to map array state to add it into `urls` in [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share)
But when I'm trying to share it, it shows `Error: uriString`
In the docs it should look like this:
`urls: [image1, image2]`. How can I do it?

Code:

```
let shareImage = {
            title: `Shared Job from Group ${groupID}`,
            email: shareEmail,
            message: `Group ID ${groupID} | License Number ${data.LicenseNumber}\nModel: ${data.Manufacturer} ${data.Model} ${data.ProductionYear}\nImages:`,
            urls: [...imagesBase64]
        };
        try {
            const shareResponse = await Share.open(shareImage);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(shareResponse));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error => ', e);
        }
```

Comment: Where does `imagesBase64` come from? How do you generate it?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue.
I have generated the `imagesBase64` inside an `useEffect` hook.
And whenever `useEffect` was called, it was adding the same images to the `imagesBase64`. So to fix it, I'm resetting the `imagesBase64` at the start of `useEffect`.